# How to use Notification service extension with UNNotification in iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, ios10, ios-extensions

Apple introduce new extension names ["UNNotificationServiceExtension"](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension), but how to launch it from push notification ?

I read that service extension provide end to end encryption for payload.

Which key is required to set payload of push notification ?

How to identify payload and how to launch service extension from push notification ?

Comment: Watch the videos. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/707/ https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/708/

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Let me take it step by step.

**UNNotificationServiceExtension - What it is?**

UNNotificationServiceExtension is an App Extenstion target that you bundle along with your app aiming to modify the push notifications as and when they are delivered to the device before rendering it to the user. You can change the title, subtitle, body and additionally add attachments to the push notification by either downloading it or using one bundled in the app.

**How to create**

Go to File -> New -> Target -> Notification Service Extension and fill in the details

**Which key is required to set payload of push notification?**

You need to set the `mutable-content` flag to `1` to trigger the service extension. 
<strike>Also, if the `content-available` is set to `1`, the service extension will not work. So either don't set it or set it to 0.</strike>
 (Edit: This is not applicable. You can set or unset `content-available` flag)

**How to identify payload and how to launch service extension from push notification?**

Build the extension and then build and run your app. Send a push notification with the `mutable-content` set to `1`.

**Code**

UNNotificationService exposes two functions:

```
- (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request
               withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent * _Nonnull))contentHandler;

- (void)serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire;
```

The first function is triggered when the push notification is received on the device and before it is presented to the user. You code inside the function has the opportunity to modify the content of the push notification inside this function.

You do this by modifying the `bestAttemptContent` property of your extension which is an instance of `UNNotificationContent` and has properties: `title`, `subtitle`, `body`, `attachments` etc.

The original payload of the remote notification is delivered via `request.content` property of function parameter `request`.

Finally you dispatch your bestAttemptContent using the contentHandler:

```
self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);
```

You have limited time to do your stuff in the first method. In case that time expires your second method is called with the best attempt your code had made thus far.

**Sample Code**

```
- (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request
               withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent * _Nonnull))contentHandler {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler;
    self.bestAttemptContent = [request.content mutableCopy];

    // Modify the notification content here...
    self.bestAttemptContent.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ [modified]", self.bestAttemptContent.title];
    self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);
}
```

The above code appends [modified] to the original title in the PN payload.

**Sample Payload**

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "title": "Hello",
            "body": "body.."
        },
        "mutable-content":1,
        "sound": "default",
        "badge": 1,

    },
  "attachment-url": ""
}
```

Please note that the `attachment-url` key is a custom key for your own concerns and not recognised by iOS .

Comment: To the point answer. Good Explanation. Specially for `You need to set the 'mutable-content' flag to 1 to trigger the service extension. Also, if the 'content-available' is set to 1, the service extension will not work.So either don't set it or set it to 0.`

Comment: Are you sure about point of "content-available" key? I use in my app and it works without problem.

Comment: @Foriger I remember I had read it somewhere and also it was mentioned that it may not work with the content-available flag turned on. I tried looking up for the same again but couldn't find it. I'll update it if I find it.

Comment: @mickeymoon can we trigger the service extension by local notification?

Comment: @DashAndRest Yes it would work as long as you set the `mutable-content` flag

Comment: Is it possible to call AppDelegate method from the service extension?

Comment: @Foriger Yes you are right about the `content-available` key. It works with that as well. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Dmitry No you cannot call UIApplication and thus not reach your app delegate, from the extension.

Comment: @Jonny can I access user preferences in the Extension? And if yes how please?

Comment: @mickeymoon can i get push data in this method if app is in background or removed from background ?

Comment: @Jonny How to pass data from AppDelegate to the extension. Do you have any blog or tutorial? Please check my question here:- https://stackoverflow.com/q/54133966/1635315

Comment: Note that if you're using firebase cloud messaging the key is named "mutable_content" not "mutable-content" (underscore vs dash)

Comment: @FreedomOfSpeech You can access user preferences by setting up App Groups for your app and extension. You need to read and write preferences to the app group's preferences, not the default ones.

Comment: `Also, if the content-available is set to 1, the service extension will not work. So either don't set it or set it to 0. (Edit: This is not applicable. You can set or unset content-available flag)` That is false. You cannot add both flags `content-available` and `mutable-content` as that would simply not send the push notification at all (that's what happened with me).  Also,  check this from OneSignal: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/data-notifications#does-confirmed-deliveries-work-with-silent-push-notifications

Comment: @NinoBouchedid Got it, at the time of writing this wasn't a limitation, but I see the link mentions the problem. If you set the content-available flag, notification is sent as a silent notification and NSE is not triggered, but if you set the body, NSE is triggered and notification is shown. So, `content-available` cannot be used to send silent notification and trigger NSE as well, as OneSignal was hoping to use it to provide delivery ack.

Comment: I tried every way. I put debug on - (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent *contentToDeliver))contentHandler {
} . I send push many times but it didn't call this method anyway. What i do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Notification service extension very useful in download content from notification data and display in notification like image and other content. you can also use notification service extension for execute some code when application is in background mode or in-active(killed).

[Here](https://www.logisticinfotech.com/blog/ios-push-notification-with-notification-service-extension/) is step by step guidelines of how to use notification service extension. And also you got the demo from from [github](https://github.com/logisticinfotech/notification-service-extension).