# iOS: perform a HTTP request, on receiving a push notification, when the app is NOT running (totally killed)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I'm working on an iOS application that handles push notifications, sent with Firebase and we need to send an SMS to the device if the notification is not received (eg: the phone is offline). To do so I need to notify the server every time the app receives a push notification, by performing a HTTP request, because if the server doesn't receive this "ack", it will send an SMS. Is there a way to do this when the app is not running and is not even "sleeping" in background?
I can't wait for the user to open the app, since after 30 seconds from the push notification, the server will send the SMS

Comment: The only thing that come to my mind that you could use is UNNotificationServiceExtension: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension. But I don't know if an app with this functionality will be approved on the store

Comment: I succeeded in using the  UNNotificationServiceExtension following this guite https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40040583/how-to-use-notification-service-extension-with-unnotification-in-ios10?answertab=votes#tab-top. I confirm that with this instrument I can make my app do things, even when the it is killed, when receiving a notification. Also I had to send the notifications using postman, since the body needed to contain the "mutable_content" value set to  true.
All I have to do now is to add an http call in the ServiceExtension. Hopefully this will cause me further problems... Thank you

Comment: Did you solve problem?